# Determine number of trees in Random Forest using python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have been using Random Forest for doing classification task. I have read some references that mention if larger number of trees is better and also we can use `OOB error rate` to get a running unbiased estimate of the classification error as trees are added to the forest.

However, by using `OOB error rate`, I still cannot determine the best number of trees in Random Forest since we should set range of the minimum and maximum number of trees that will be evaluated. Because, It is possible if the best number of trees can be found out of set range. In here, I need your advanced advice, how to the OOB error rate returns the best number of trees in Random Forest exactly. The following below is a code that uses OOB error rate with the specific range of minimum and maximum of number of trees (10 up to 100):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from collections import OrderedDict
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


ensemble_clfs = [ ("RandomForestClassifier, max_features=None",RandomForestClassifier(warm_start=True, max_features=None, oob_score=True,))]


error_rate = OrderedDict((label, []) for label, _ in ensemble_clfs)


min_estimators = 10
max_estimators = 100

for label, clf in ensemble_clfs:
    for i in range(min_estimators, max_estimators + 1):
        clf.set_params(n_estimators=i)
        clf.fit(X, Y)
        oob_error = 1 - clf.oob_score_
        error_rate[label].append((i, oob_error))


for label, clf_err in error_rate.items():
    xs, ys = zip(*clf_err)
    plt.plot(xs, ys, label=label)

plt.xlim(min_estimators, max_estimators)
plt.xlabel("n_estimators")
plt.ylabel("OOB error rate")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

The results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no specified value that you need to aim for, it's whatever you feel comfortable as the error. Is 0.1 error rate good for you? Or do you need 0.05? It all depends on the data you're working with. In some cases I've seen 0.2 acceptable.

---

With that being said, couple of things about the code you're working with:

1. The reason you see the "jagged" line as your `n_estimators` increase is because you're not comparing error rate properly. You need to define `random_state` in your `RandomForestClassifier` that way you're pulling from the same pool
2. At some point performance and speed will be more important than your accuracy, and that's when you need to decide what's more important. Let's say at `n_estimators = 100` you have 0.2 error and it took you ~10 minutes to run (depends on your data, just a rough estimate). However, at `n_estimators = 1000` your error rate is 0.18, but it took you ~25 mintues to run. Is that extra 15 minutes worth the 0.02 imporvement? It all depends on type of data you're working with.
3. Change your step to 5, possibly 3 if you need a finer solution and see where it levels out at. A step size of 1 might be too small to get a general overview of your error rate. From there you change refine your scope once you have a general idea of where your error rate to speed diverge.